# make responsive full screen background image have fixed button

Tags: html, css, background-image

first of all i wanna a responsive full screen background image.
i know that there is a lot of tutorials in the web, but in my case there is a fixed button on a special area of image which is clickable  and by click on it user must go to next page! indeed this page is a initial page for my website.
my earlier solution was using jQuery where i calculate screen size and according to size background image changes:

```
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();
    //....
```

is there html css solution for that ?
thank.

Comment: sure, where is the position of the button, center (vertical and horizontal)? or somewhere :D

Comment: that can be every where! :D but now bottom right!

Answer (score 1):

background-size: cover automatically resize the picture to fit screen and absolute position with left and top in percents sticks the button on the same place relatively to the picture. See the following sample in the full screen mode and try to resize the browser window:

```css
body{
  background-image: url('http://tinytour.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/beautiful-paris-wallpaper-for-home.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
input[type='button']{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 73%;
}
```

```html
<input type='button' value='press me!' />
```

Comment: thank, thats a good idea. but in some window size background repeats!
and if we set background-repeat:no-repeat image is small in other cases and a white area appears in bottom.

Comment: To ensure that image can properly cover any screen size you should make it large enough. I'd recommend 1920x1080px to comply with the most standard wide screen size on desktop computers.